# Choose random code within switch statement

Tags: php, web, random, switch-statement

I'm using a switch statement with several cases.

When one of the cases is chosen, how can I randomly choose a block of code within that case, but **without** using a nested switch statement?

For example:

```
switch ($choose_case){

case 1:
//some code
break;

case 2:
//some code
break;

case 3:
(random block of code #1)
(random block of code #2)
=randomly choose #1 or #2
break;

}
```

Comment: I don't really see what you goal is with this code, please make an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In don't know about you but i will do it like this.

```
switch ($choose_case){

case 1:
//some code
break;

case 2:
//some code
break;

case 3:
$var = rand(1,2);
  if($var == 1)
  {
     //case 1 
  }
  else
  {
     //case 2
  }

break;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that is by attributing $choose_value a random number between 1 and 2 and calling the function that contains the switch again with the new value. So, in your case:

```
function do_something($choose_case){

 switch ($choose_case){

   case 1:
   //some code
   break;

   case 2:
   //some code
   break;

   case 3:
   $choose_case = floor(rand(1.5,2.5));
   do_something($choose_case);
   break;

}
```